# Python регистрация в инстаграм

Tags: python, instagram

У кого-нибудь есть рабочий код для регистрации инстаграмм акка из питона? Пойдет любой - без прокси, впн, и прочего. просто голая регистрация.
   И еще вопрос. Мой нерабочий код получает ответ и ошибку в нем 'generic_request_error'. Что это  может значить?

Comment: чем не угодила документация и  примеры на просторах интернета? и мы знаем почему эта ошибка вылазит, мы же видим код =)

Comment: У кого-нибудь точно есть.

Comment: В том то и дело, что на просторах интернета нет рабочего кода!  все спрашивают почему у них что-то не работает(( суть в том что в модуле requests сам не шарю на уровне чего-то сложного, типа ajax запросов или еще чего то там. поэтому хочу рабочий код достать чтобы от него уже отталкиваться)

Comment: про ошибку  я имел ввиду с инсты прилетает json с котором такой код оштбки - думал мб опытные гики сразу скажут мол это про то-то и про то-то

Comment: @АндрейПетрушов тебе все тонко намекают что бы ты приложил свой код. На такие общие вопросы тут ответа давать не будут. Ты просто ленишься и пытаешь решить задачу  "с пол тычка".

Comment: Да, Вы правы, с полтычка. Эт конечно неправильно. Короче расскажу. У меня код для каждого запроса регистрации выводит "Ваш ip был помечен как открытый прокси, ...". Пробовал с разных сетей, пробовал разные абсолютно чистые почты... Сейчас заново создам. спасибо!